# Shell scripting: While loop exits prematurely

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script to resign .ipa files. you can run it with:

```
./mrs.sh -i eliterature.ipa -d "eliterature 123" -v 3.8.0.0 -s 3.8.0 -b com.company.eliterature.123
```

In the beginning there is a while loop that checks for all given options:

```
echo "Signing with following options: "

while getopts "h?i:b:t:p:v:s:d:x" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
    h|\?)
        show_help
        exit 0
        ;;
    i)  echo "  - Ipa Path: ${OPTARG}"
        ipa_path=$OPTARG
        ;;
    b)  echo "  - Bundle ID: ${OPTARG}"
        CFBundleIdentifier_new=$OPTARG
        ;;
    t)  echo "  - Team ID: ${OPTARG}"
        teamid_new=$OPTARG
        ;;
    p)  echo "  - Provisioning Profile: ${OPTARG}"
        provisioning_profile=$OPTARG
        ;;
    v)  echo "  - CFBundleVersion: ${OPTARG}"
        CFBundleVersion_new=$OPTARG
        ;;
    s)  echo "  - CFBundleShortVersionString: ${OPTARG}"
        CFBundleShortVersionString_new=$OPTARG
        ;;
    d)  echo "  - Display Name: ${OPTARG}"
        CFBundleDisplayName_new=$OPTARG
        ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

The problem is always with the last option that gets ignored. If the while loop is declared like this:

```
while getopts "h?i:b:t:p:v:s:d" opt; do
```

the `-d` option is ignored. If I add an extra letter to the declaration, the `-d` option is executed:

```
while getopts "h?i:b:t:p:v:s:d:x" opt; do
```

How do I get the while loop to work correctly without adding any extra unused letters?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a trailing colon? Like `"h?i:b:t:p:v:s:d:"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a colon `:` after `d` which is required to pass an argument after `-d` on command line.

As per `man 1 getopt`:

> **if a letter is followed by a colon**,
>        the option is expected to have an argument which may or may not be separated from it by white space

**Working code:**

```
echo "Signing with following options: "

while getopts "h?i:b:t:p:v:s:d:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
    h|\?)
        show_help
        exit 0
        ;;
    i)  echo "  - Ipa Path: ${OPTARG}"
        ipa_path=$OPTARG
        ;;
    b)  echo "  - Bundle ID: ${OPTARG}"
        CFBundleIdentifier_new=$OPTARG
        ;;
    t)  echo "  - Team ID: ${OPTARG}"
        teamid_new=$OPTARG
        ;;
    p)  echo "  - Provisioning Profile: ${OPTARG}"
        provisioning_profile=$OPTARG
        ;;
    v)  echo "  - CFBundleVersion: ${OPTARG}"
        CFBundleVersion_new=$OPTARG
        ;;
    s)  echo "  - CFBundleShortVersionString: ${OPTARG}"
        CFBundleShortVersionString_new=$OPTARG
        ;;
    d)  echo "  - Display Name: ${OPTARG}"
        CFBundleDisplayName_new=$OPTARG
        ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
```